# Linq Expression Calling Combines

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, expression

How to combine these expression

```
Expression<Func<int, int>> f1 = i => i + 1;
Expression<Func<int, int>> f2 = i => i + 2;
Expression<Func<int, int, int>> f3 = (i, j) => i * j;
```

to

```
Expression<Func<int, int>> f4 = i =>(i+1)*(i+2);
```

while running?

---

Here's the code. I want to write a extend method but it don't work in linq2entities

```
public static IQueryable<TRe> LeftJoin<TLeft, TRight, TKey, TRe>(this IQueryable<TLeft> left, IQueryable<TRight> right, Expression<Func<TLeft, TKey>> leftKeySel, Expression<Func<TRight, TKey>> rightKeySel, Expression<Func<TLeft, TRight, TRe>> reSel)
{
    return left.GroupJoin(right, leftKeySel, rightKeySel, (l, r) => new { l, r }).SelectMany(p => p.r.DefaultIfEmpty(), (p, r) => new { p.l, r }).Select1(p => p.l, p => p.r, reSel);
}
public static IQueryable<TRe> Select1<TSrc, T1, T2, TRe>(this IQueryable<TSrc> src, Expression<Func<TSrc, T1>> f1, Expression<Func<TSrc, T2>> f2, Expression<Func<T1, T2, TRe>> func)
{

    var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSrc));

    var a = Expression.Invoke(f1, p);
    var b = Expression.Invoke(f2, p);
    var c = Expression.Invoke(func, a, b);

    return src.Select(Expression.Lambda<Func<TSrc, TRe>>(c, p));
}
```

and this code called LeftJoin method:

```
var re = _db.Accounts.OrderBy(p => p.LoginDays).Take(100).LeftJoin(_db.PasswordHistorys, p => p.Email, p => p.Email, (a, b) => new
{
    a,
    b.PasswordOld
});
```

Comment: This question would have been better if it had included the *code of a minimal example* that you tried and an explanation about how/why it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "i");
var r = Expression
    .Invoke(f3, new[] { 
        Expression.Invoke(f1, p), 
        Expression.Invoke(f2, p) });

Expression<Func<int, int>> lam = Expression.Lambda<Func<int, int>>(r, p);
```

As per comments, it is possible to do this:

```
var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "i");
var lam = Expression.Lambda<Func<int, int>>(Expression.Multiply(f1.Body, f2.Body), p);
```

or

```
var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "i");
var lam = Expression.Lambda<Func<int, int>>(Expression.Add(f1.Body, f2.Body), p);
```

---

## Solution with expression visitors

So, I managed to come up with a bit of a hack to replace the parameter references with `f1` and `f2`.
However, it makes the following assumptions:

1. `f3` has exactly two parameters.
2. `f1` ,`f2` and `f3` all have the exact same method signatures

Here's the implementation:

```
public class SuperHack : ExpressionVisitor
{   
    private Dictionary<ParameterExpression, LambdaExpression> _replacements;
    private ParameterExpression _newParameter;
    public SuperHack(Dictionary<ParameterExpression, LambdaExpression> replacements, ParameterExpression newParameter)
    {
        _replacements = replacements ?? new Dictionary<ParameterExpression, LambdaExpression>();
        _newParameter = newParameter;
    }

    public Expression Modify(Expression expression)
    {
        var res = Visit(expression);
        return res;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitLambda<T>(Expression<T> e)
    {
        return Expression.Lambda(Visit(e.Body), _newParameter);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression e)
    {
        if (_replacements.ContainsKey(e))
            return Visit(Expression.Lambda(_replacements[e].Body, _newParameter).Body);

        return base.VisitParameter(_newParameter);
    }
}
```

And here's how you use it:

```
Expression<Func<int, int>> f1 = i => i + 1;
Expression<Func<int, int>> f2 = i => i + 2;
Expression<Func<int, int, int>> f3 = (i, j) => i * j;

var @params = f3.Parameters;
var mapping = new Dictionary<ParameterExpression, LambdaExpression>
{
    {@params[0], f1},
    {@params[1], f2}
};

var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "i");
var f4 = new SuperHack(mapping, p).Modify(f3) as Expression<Func<int,int>>;
```

The result is:

```
i => ((i + 1) * (i + 2))
```

No invokes needed!

Comment: Expression<Func<int, int>> lam = Expression.Lambda<Func<int, int>>(r, p); this expression can not use in linq2sql, even its result is same with f4

Comment: You should have mentioned you're using it for `linq2sql` in the original question. However, `Expression.Lambda` is almost definitely not the problem . It may be due to the `Invoke`. Can you show the error you're getting?

Comment: @zEvolution I just tested this with linq2sql, it does in fact work.

Comment: The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.-------that's not linq2sql but linq2entities, my mistake

Comment: the lam expression body use invoke to call f1 and f2, but f4 only use add and multiply, I am finding a way to get an expression has same body with f4

Comment: @zEvolution There isn't really a way to do it completely dynamically, then.  It's not feasible to re-build the expression trees that way. It's possible if you are happy to remove `f3` and combine `f1` and `f2` with multiplication (or add).

Comment: but I don't know f3 while I am writting my code, and it's not feasible to re-build the expression trees for me but feasible to someone who knows well in expression

Comment: @zEvolution Had a bit of spare time at work, so I whipped up a quick way to get it to work.. take a look at the edit.

Comment: The SuperHack class may solve my problem and it will take times for me to understand this code. I believe this code can show the way to learn expression deeply, thank you.

Comment: @zEvolution Hey mate, glad it all worked out for you. I wasn't extremely happy with the final answer I came to - it's way too brittle for my liking. I've added an alternative answer which may work better for you if you ever need to write more complex expressions. Hopefully helps someone else out, too.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't entirely happy with my other solution (though it may be helpful to others who aren't concerned with `Invoke` calls within the Expression, so I'll leave it up).

The work-around to replace parameters with actual expressions is flaky at best, and very brittle. After a bit of thinking, it seems more logical to simply replace all `Invoke` calls with their respective expressions, substituting the parameter with the argument.

This allows you to write much more complex queries, and may be of use to someone who is migrating from `Linq-To-Sql` to `EntityFramework`. It also opens us up to performing further tweaks to allow `EntityFramework` to properly run.

End up writing something like this:

```
var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "i");
var r = Expression
    .Invoke(f3, new[] { 
        Expression.Invoke(f1, p), 
        Expression.Invoke(f2, p) }) 
    .InlineInvokes();

Expression<Func<int, int>> lam = Expression.Lambda<Func<int, int>>(r, p);
```

Which takes this expression:

```
i => Invoke((i, j) => (i * j), Invoke(i => (i + 1), i), Invoke(i => (i + 2), i))
```

And replaces it with this:

```
i => ((i + 1) * (i + 2))
```

Or for the more complex:

```
b => Invoke((d, e) => (d * e), Invoke(b => (50 + Invoke(z => (25 + Invoke(h => (h * 8), z)), b)), b), Invoke(c => (c + 2), b))
```

Produces

```
b => ((50 + (25 + (b * 8))) * (b + 2))
```

Implementation:

```
public static class ExpressionHelpers
{
    public static Expression InlineInvokes<T>(this T expression)
        where T : Expression
    {
        return (T)new InvokeInliner().Inline(expression);
    }

    public static Expression InlineInvokes(this InvocationExpression expression)
    {
        return new InvokeInliner().Inline(expression);
    }

    public class InvokeInliner : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        private Stack<Dictionary<ParameterExpression, Expression>> _context = new Stack<Dictionary<ParameterExpression, Expression>>();
        public Expression Inline(Expression expression)
        {
            return Visit(expression);
        }

        protected override Expression VisitInvocation(InvocationExpression e)
        {
            var callingLambda = ((LambdaExpression)e.Expression);
            var currentMapping = new Dictionary<ParameterExpression, Expression>();
            for (var i = 0; i < e.Arguments.Count; i++)
            {
                var argument = Visit(e.Arguments[i]);
                var parameter = callingLambda.Parameters[i];
                if (parameter != argument)
                    currentMapping.Add(parameter, argument);
            }
            _context.Push(currentMapping);
            var result = Visit(callingLambda.Body);
            _context.Pop();
            return result;
        }

        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression e)
        {
            if (_context.Count > 0)
            {
                var currentMapping = _context.Peek();
                if (currentMapping.ContainsKey(e))
                    return currentMapping[e];
            }
            return e;
        }
    }
}
```

How it works:

Whenever we hit an `Invoke` expression, we store the values being passed to the invoke, as well as the parameters of the expression being invoked. For example, if we had an invoke like this:

`Invoke(f1, Expression.Constant(1))` and `f1` was defined as `i => { i + 1; }` we define a mapping from `i => Expression.Constant(1)`

We then continue parsing the from the lambda expression's *body*, since we are no longer using parameters.

Then we capture visits to `Parameter`. Here, we look at the current mappings defined. If there's a mapping for the parameter, we return the substitute value verbatim. If there's no mapping, we simply return the parameter.

Comment: This code may be the best answer for my question. Notice the T cast after calling Inline method will fail because the expression is an InvocationExpression but not in the result after inline.

Comment: @zEvolution Oh yes, you're right - I added the templates at the end as a nice-to-have - didn't think about running the method on an `InvokeExpression` itself. I've updated the answer

Comment: I tried modify the extend method to this ----------<code> public static Expression<T> InlineInvokes<T>(this Expression expression, params ParameterExpression[] parameters)
  {
   return Expression.Lambda<T>(new InvokeInliner().Inline(expression), parameters);
  }</code>

Comment: @zEvolution We can't always return a lambda expression, since the inline can be on any type (on binary expressions, for example). I've updated the post so that it properly returns the `Expression` you pass in, unless it's explicitly an `InvocationExpression`, in which case we return an `Expression`

Comment: So that I would write another extend method to get a lambda expression if I want