# Using custom methods that return IQueryable in the LINQ to entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I have two methods that return IQueryable:

```
IQueryable<Person> GetGoodPeople();
```

and

```
IQueryable<Person> GetBadPeople();
```

I need to write this query:

```
var q = from x in GetGoodPeople()
        from y in GetBadPeople()
        select new { Good = x, Bad = y };
```

The above code is not supported in the linq to entities (the `NotSupportedException` is thrown), except I declare a variable and use it in the query:

```
var bad = GetBadPeople()
var q = from x in GetGoodPeople()
        from y in bad
        select new { Good = x, Bad = y };
```

Is there a way that I can use IQueryable methods in the linq to entities directly?

Comment: What error are you getting while execution? and also show us GetGoodPeople() implementation

Comment: The exception is: `System.NotSupportedException

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[...] Query[...]()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
'

Comment: have you tried with properties : `IQueryable<Person> GetGoodPeople {get; set;}`

Comment: The properties work well, but if I need some parameters, they won't help.

Comment: can you try using .ToList like this GetGoodPeople.ToList().Select(x => ...)

Comment: tries using the Linq extension .AsEnumerable() on the GetBadpeople() call

Comment: as @barakcaf also suggested try using Persons.Select(x => x.whatever).AsEnumerable().Select(
    (whatever, index) => new
    {
        rn = index + 1,
        col1 = whatever
    }).ToList();

Comment: Beware that using ToList() executes the query eagerly and not in a lazy fashion

Comment: While it is *possible* to do this, any solution to this problem would unquestionably be more work than your current solution of simply using a local.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer - it's not <s>possible</s> feasible. Your fix is the correct way to solve the problem.

Once entity framework (and LINQ2Sql as well) begins parsing the expression tree, it's too late. The call to `GetBadPeople()` is actually lazily executed, and as such, is attempted to be converted into SQL *itself*.

Here's what it may look like:

```
Table(Person).Take(1).SelectMany(x => value(UserQuery).GetBadPeople(), (x, y) => new <>f__AnonymousType0`2(Good = x, Bad = y))
```

Here, I've written `GetGoodPeople()` as simply returning `People.Take(1)`. Note how that query is *verbatim*, but `GetBadPeople()` contains a function call.

Your workaround of evaluating `GetBadPeople()` outside of the expression is the correct solution. This causes the expression tree to call `Expression.Constant(bad)`, rather than attemping to invoke `GetBadPeople()`.

That makes the query look like this:

```
Table(Person).Take(1).SelectMany(x => value(UserQuery+<>c__DisplayClass1_0).bad, (x, y) => new <>f__AnonymousType0`2(Good = x, Bad = y))
```

Note there's no method invocation here - we simply pass in the variable.

Comment: It's *possible*, just...not nearly as easy.  You'd need to transform the first expression into the second.  You can write a method to do that.

Comment: @Servy You're right, I was perhaps too black & white with the response (in that it's not *feasible*). I actually have a solution to inline invokes [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34408179/linq-expression-calling-combines/34416123#34416123) - though it takes a little more work when using fluent syntax

Comment: Sorry, I meant query syntax

Comment: Interestingly, I never thought about this before, but why we can use then properties/methods from `DbContext`, e.g. `from a in db.TableA from b in db.TableB select new { a, b }` works?

Comment: @IvanStoev You're able to use properties because the translator makes the assumption that the property is merely an empty getter/setter. If it seems a property on an entity, it directly translates it into a reference to a column. There are some assumptions baked into the translator that makes things work. Methods, on the other hand, will never be translated unless they're part of a few whitelisted methods (for example min, count, group by, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You can approximate a cartesian product by using an unconstrained join. It doesn't seem to be susceptible to the NotSupportedException. I checked the backend and it renders a single sql statement.

```
var q = from x in GetGoodPeople()
        join y in GetBadPeople()
        on 1 equals 1
        select new { Good = x, Bad = y };
```

Comment: The problem is the method to produce the `IQueryable` inside the query, as the query provider doesn't know what to do with that method.  This in no way addresses that problem.

Comment: @Servy ...Except for the fact that Linq-to-entity interprets the join correctly, the same way the OP's workaround of declaring a variable works. How does that not address the problem?